# Can Jackson check for duplicated properties in a case insensitive way?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am using Jackson JSON to convert some JSON objects to POJO classes. This deserialization should be **case insensitive**, and it should not allow attributes with **case insensitive** duplicate names.

Configuring the `ObjectMapper` as shown below enables case insensitive deserialization and failing upon attributes which have strictly the same name:

```java
final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
objectMapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION);
```

However it does not fail when the input contains two attributes with same names and different case, such as the following:

```
{
   "Name": "name01",
   "NAME": "name02"
}
```

Is there any way to configure`ObjectMapper` to fail under such circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION` documentation:

> Feature that determines whether JsonParser will explicitly check that
>   no duplicate JSON Object field names are encountered. If enabled,
>   parser will check all names within context and report duplicates by
>   throwing a JsonParseException; if disabled, parser will not do such
>   checking. **Assumption in latter case is that caller takes care of**
>   **handling duplicates at a higher level: data-binding, for example**, has
>   features to specify detection to be done there. Note that enabling
>   this feature will incur performance overhead due to having to store
>   and check additional information: this typically adds 20-30% to
>   execution time for basic parsing.

`JSON` by default is case sensitive and this one of main reason why making it insensitive is not enabled by default in `Jackson`. But we can extend basic implementation and add validation. We need to extend `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer` which deserialises `POJO` classes. Below solution depends from version you are using because I copied some code from base class which is not ready for intercepting extra functionality. If you do not have any extra configuration for your `POJO` classes `vanillaDeserialize` method will be invoked and this one we will try to improve. Let's implement it:

```
class InsensitiveBeanDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        JsonDeserializer<?> base = super.modifyDeserializer(config, beanDesc, deserializer);
        if (base instanceof BeanDeserializer) {
            return new InsensitiveBeanDeserializer((BeanDeserializer) base);
        }

        return base;
    }
}

class InsensitiveBeanDeserializer extends BeanDeserializer {

    public InsensitiveBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerBase src) {
        super(src);
    }

    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        // common case first
        if (p.isExpectedStartObjectToken()) {
            if (_vanillaProcessing) {
                return vanillaDeserialize(p, ctxt, p.nextToken());
            }
            // 23-Sep-2015, tatu: This is wrong at some many levels, but for now... it is
            //    what it is, including "expected behavior".
            p.nextToken();
            if (_objectIdReader != null) {
                return deserializeWithObjectId(p, ctxt);
            }
            return deserializeFromObject(p, ctxt);
        }
        return _deserializeOther(p, ctxt, p.getCurrentToken());
    }

    protected Object vanillaDeserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, JsonToken t) throws IOException {
        final Object bean = _valueInstantiator.createUsingDefault(ctxt);
        // [databind#631]: Assign current value, to be accessible by custom serializers
        p.setCurrentValue(bean);
        Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<>();
        if (p.hasTokenId(JsonTokenId.ID_FIELD_NAME)) {
            String propName = p.getCurrentName();
            do {
                String oldName = names.put(propName.toLowerCase(), propName);
                if (oldName != null) {
                    String msg = "Properties '" + propName + "' and '" + oldName + "' are the same!";
                    throw new DuplicateInsensitiveKeysException(p, msg);
                }

                defaultImplementation(p, ctxt, bean, propName);
            } while ((propName = p.nextFieldName()) != null);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    private void defaultImplementation(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, Object bean, String propName) throws IOException {
        p.nextToken();
        SettableBeanProperty prop = _beanProperties.find(propName);

        if (prop != null) { // normal case
            try {
                prop.deserializeAndSet(p, ctxt, bean);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                wrapAndThrow(e, bean, propName, ctxt);
            }
            return;
        }
        handleUnknownVanilla(p, ctxt, bean, propName);
    }

    public static class DuplicateInsensitiveKeysException extends JsonMappingException {

        public DuplicateInsensitiveKeysException(Closeable processor, String msg) {
            super(processor, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonTokenId;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new InsensitiveBeanDeserializerModifier());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        mapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, User.class));
    }
}
```

For above `JSON` payloads prints:

```
Exception in thread "main" InsensitiveBeanDeserializer$DuplicateInsensitiveKeysException: Properties 'NAME' and 'Name' are the same!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detail answer, it was really nice of you! I will try you proposal right away and let you know how it went.

Comment: It did work, the only issue is that the proposed solution is not compatible with additional configuration, such as `ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES`, but still I think I can figure out something. Thanks again for taking the time to provide such a complete answer!

Comment: @Serchu, I am glad to hear that. I tested this solution with `ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` and it worked for me without any problems. Example `InsensitiveBeanDeserializer` uses implementation from `BeanDeserializer` which comes from `Jackson` and depends from `Jackson`'s version. My example works properly with latest version [2.9.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.8). In case you use different version you need to copy code from current version. Could you try to create simple app and use above example with `2.9.8` version?