# How to use different object mapper properties for different subobjects

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

Consider a case like below. I want to serialize ClassA object s.t. I use different object mapper properties for `bObject` and `cObject`

```java
    class ClassA {
        ClassB bObject = new ClassB();
        ClassC cObject = new ClassC();
    }

    class ClassB {
        ClassD dObject  = new ClassD();
    }

    class ClassC {
        ClassD dObject = new ClassD();
    }

    class ClassD {
        int firstMember = 1;
        String second_member = "Two";
    }

    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE);
        objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new ClassA()));
    }
```

e.g. I want to use `PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` for `bObject` and `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` for `cObject`

The serialized json should look like :

```
{
  "bObject" : {
    "dObject" : {
      "firstMember" : 1,
      "secondMember" : "Two"
       .... similarly camel case for any nested ....
    }
  },
  "cObject" : {
    "d_object" : {
      "first_member" : 1,
      "second_member" : "Two"
       .... similarly snake case for any nested ....
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried adding `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)` & `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)` to `ClassB` and `ClassC` respectively . That fixes the name for `dObject` but not for the fields within it.

Any suggestions ? If I could use Mix-ins or custom serializer & deserializer ?

Context on why I need to do so : My current POJO is `classA` which uses `classB` and used at our service boundaries and is being serialized with a certain config. We're now adding `ClassC` (not owned by us) to POJO. Serializers/Derserialzer for `classC` need to follow a different convention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Relaxed" fields names for Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846834/relaxed-fields-names-for-jackson)

Comment: @MichałZiober Not really. I want to serialize and deserialize in the same format to keep the format consistent.

Comment: how do i remove possible duplicate tag from this ?