# Duplicate XML tags are not detected even when required properties are used

Tags: java, xml, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I have a Springboot webservice application and I am using Jackson tags for XML and JSON. For JSON I am able to identify duplicates but not in XML.
To detect duplicates in JSON following config is used

```
spring:
   jackson:
      deserialization:
         fail-on-unknown-properties: true
      parser:
         STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION: true
```

DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY or JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION none of them are working with XML input

Config to detect duplicate is as given below

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name = "xmlmapper")
    public ObjectMapper xmlObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY);
        mapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Now when we give XML with duplicate element it is not throwing error by default it selects second tag value

```
<Test>
   <A>v1</A>
   <A>v2</A>
</Test>
```

Corresponding class is given below

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="Test")
public class Test {
      @JsonProperty("A")
      @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="A")
      protected String a;
}
```

Expected result is it should throw error when duplicate tags are passed in XML but it does not. I do not want to use case insensitivity as that would cause another issue.

Comment: Is this a flag that can be applied to XML parsing?

Comment: These flags are supposed to work only for JSon serialization.

Comment: How I can detect duplicates for XML then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know... I tried to find an answer googling it, right now, but I still didn't find any answer...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado You could validate the XML document against an XSD specifying the XML structure that you allow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Jackson check for duplicated properties in a case insensitive way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376094/can-jackson-check-for-duplicated-properties-in-a-case-insensitive-way). My solution in this question should work for `XmlMapper` as well. Also, you do not need to enable `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` feature. Check version of `Jackson` which you use because this solution depends from used version.

Comment: @MichałZiober thanks for comment but it seems your solution is not what I am expecting